# Manually trigger a wx.EVT_SIZE event

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

In order to refresh my GUI, sometimes `self.Refresh()`, `self.Layout()` doesn't produce the result I want.

The only thing that worked and really refreshed the GUI is : manually triggering a `wx.EVT_SIZE` with

```
s = self.GetSize()
self.SetSize((0,0))
self.SetSize(s)
```

Is there a *cleaner* way of manually triggering a `wx.EVT_SIZE` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wxWindow::PostSizeEvent()`.

Notice, however, that if you avoided the manual handling of `wxEVT_SIZE` (which you seem to be doing based on your other questions) and just used sizers, then a simple `Layout()` would be enough.

And, FWIW, `Refresh()` has nothing to do with size at all, it just results in repainting the window, i.e. can be used to trigger a call to your `wxEVT_PAINT`, not `wxEVT_SIZE`, handler.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how is it called in `wxpython`?